# Error: Could not find or load main class ocpjp1.I_O_fundamentals.console.FormattedTable

Tags: java

I'm trying to run the program on linux ubuntu using intellij idea IDE terminal, but kept getting "Error: Could not find or load main class ocpjp1.I_O_fundamentals.console.FormattedTable" ... Any help please?

I have tried this on the terminal:
/IdeaProjects/ocpjp/out/production/ocpjp/ocpjp1/I_O_fundamentals/console$ java ocpjp1.I_O_fundamentals.console.FormattedTable

**This is the code below:**

```
package ocpjp1.I_O_fundamentals.console;

import java.io.Console;

public class FormattedTable {
    void line(Console console) {
        console.printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    void printHeader(Console console) {
        console.printf("%-15s \t %s \t %s \t %s \n", "Player", "Matches", "Goals",
                "Goals per match");
    }
    void printRow(Console console, String player, int matches, int goals) {
        console.printf("%-15s \t %5d \t\t %d \t\t %.1f \n", player, matches, goals,
                ((float)goals/(float)matches));
    }
    public static void main(String[] str) {
        FormattedTable formattedTable = new FormattedTable();
        Console console = System.console();
        if(console != null) {
            formattedTable.line(console);
            formattedTable.printHeader(console);
            formattedTable.line(console);
            formattedTable.printRow(console, "Demando", 100, 122);
            formattedTable.printRow(console, "Mushi", 80, 100);
            formattedTable.printRow(console, "Peale", 150, 180);
            formattedTable.line(console);
        }
    }
}
```

the program is to be executed in the console(using terminal) but is giving: Error: Could not find or load main class ocpjp1.I_O_fundamentals.console.FormattedTable

Comment: You need to execute that from the directory `/IdeaProjects/ocpjp/out/production/ocpjp`. Or to set the classpath to `../../..`, or to set the classpath to `/IdeaProjects/ocpjp/out/production/ocpjp`. I.e. the directory containing the root of the package tree must be in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I executed it from the directory /IdeaProjects/ocpjp/out/production/ocpjp....though I didn't set the class path because I don't know how to.

Comment: The classpath is `.` (i.e. the current directory) by default.

Comment: 'ocpjp' is the root directory and it has already been in the classpath.